Accessing QField data on iOS
I have some digitalising data in a qfield project, and for reasons I want to export this data via cable, not via QField Cloud (the project owner does not like the data). I have been looking at this for a while now, but it seems that the QField app has stored this data in unaccessible app-data folders. See screenshot 1. The accessible folders ("QField", in "On my iphone"), are empty, see screenshot 2. Does anyone know what to do? Is it hopeless?



use itunes "Imported projects and datasets can be accessed directly using a USB cable by navigating to the QField application folder using iTunes on Windows and macOS" at the very bottom https://docs.qfield.org/get-started/storage/

As said in the question, I have done that, but these folders are empty.
